# Getting name of presenting view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller and a table view cell. On it is a separate .xib file on its own outside of storyboard. In the view controller, I register that xib/nib and then use it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as below:

```
if (indexPath.row == 2 || indexPath.row == 3 || indexPath.row == 4) {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCustomCell") as? MyCustomCell {
        return cell
    }
}

private func registerNibs() {
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "MyCustomCellView", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCustomCell")
}
```

This cell has a button which when clicked it navigates the app to a different view controller. For this I want the name of the presenting view controller when the user clicks on a button.

I can use `UIApplication.shared.topMostViewController()`, but was trying to figure out if there is a better way to get the presenting view controller from a button click?

Comment: What is "the name of the presenting view controller"? You want to identify on which cell was button pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can understand your question. You want to present a new view controller as soon user taps on a button, which is defined in a cell (`MyCustomCell`).

If it is so, there are many good ways of doing this, one of them is given below

## Delegation Design pattern

Delegation is a design pattern that enables a class or structure to hand off (or delegate) some of its responsibilities to an instance of another type.

#### 1. Create a protocol `MyCustomCellDelegate`

```swift
protocol MyCustomCellDelegate: class {
    func didTap(customCell: MyCustomCell)
}

// Assuming it is the class which inherit from UITableViewCell
class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    // Declare a public property so that you can set it from outside while initializing the cell
    weak var delegate: MyCustomCellDelegate?
    
    //function which will be called as soon user taps on the button
    
    @IBAction func didUserTapped() {
        delegate?.didTap(customCell: self)        
    }
}
```

#### Confirm the protocol

Where you want to listen to the button touch events. In your case, it is a Viewcontroller (Let say its name is `HomeViewController`), which has the `UITableView`, should confirm to `MyCustomCellDelegate` protocol.

```swift
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDatasource, UITableViewDelegate, MyCustomCellDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if (indexPath.row == 2 || indexPath.row == 3 || indexPath.row == 4) {
            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCustomCell") as? MyCustomCell {
                // Set the delegate, so that whenever user tap on button you can get the callback on the confirming class (for your case it is Current viewcontroller)
                cell.delegate = self
                return cell
            }
        }
    }
    
    //Define the delegate function which will be called once user tap on a button
    func didTap(customCell: MyCustomCell) {
        // Here you can write the logic to present/push the new view controller accordingly
    }
}
```

[More about delegation design pattern](https://www.objc.io/issues/7-foundation/communication-patterns/#delegation)

[Another good read](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/delegation-in-swift/)